# DLLExport 'NSBin.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, build

I was trying to move a build to a new build server and I was getting the following error:

**..\packages\DllExport.1.5.2\tools\net.r_eg.DllExport.targets(70,7): error MSB3073: The command "NSBin.bat "" "SPDbUtil" "true"" exited with code 9009.**

**'NSBin.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:52)**

The project has a reference to the following DllExport:

[image]

In looking at the following .targets file, it appears when running the Exec command the $(DllExportMetaLibFullPath), where the NSBin.bat file lives, is blank at the time it is called:

[image]

When I checked out the project and try and build it, it fails the first time and succeeds on consecutive builds.

If I add "echo $(DllExportMetaLibFullPath)" to the <PreBuildEvent> of the project- it builds successfully the first time.

Does anyone know why this happens? Am I missing something? BTW: this is an older project that I was trying to move to a new build system. The previous builds were completing because the build defs "Clean" option was "false". I can keep the echo in there but would be nice to know the correct way to handle this or have a definitive answer for the devs.

Thanks